# Creating a new array from a subset of another one

Tags: python, arrays

I need to create an array, correct_data, that is a subset of another one, all_data. This is all_data:

```
all_data = np.array([[[ 0, 11, 12, 13, 14],
                      [ 0, 21, 22, 23, 24],
                      [ 1, 31, 32, 33, 34],
                      [ 0, 41, 42, 43, 44]]])
```

The array correct_data will have all the the rows in all_data where the first item is a 1.
The way I was doing it is by creating a mask that identifies the rows starting with 1, such as:

`correct_mask=all_data[:,0]==1`

and then identifies the indexes of such rows (using "where").

Then I create a for loop that takes each row from the index and copy it onto correct_data (using vstack?).
Is this a practical way of doing it? If so, I need to create at fist correct_data as an empty array: can this be done?

Alternatively, I have tried to do it in a different way, i.e., delete the rows starting with a 0 from all_data

This is what I was trying:

```
for row in range(len(all_data)):
    this_row=all_data[row]
    if (this_row[0])==0:
        np.delete(all_data,row,0)
```

This does delete the rows, but then again how do I store the remaining rows in a new (or the same) array?

Many thanks for any help and clarification (I have a very basic knowledge of Python).

Comment: So you want to extract all rows that start with 1?

Comment: Yes and create another array with them.

Answer (score 1):

You can just filter it with an index condition:

```
>>> all_data[all_data[:,:,0]==1]
array([[ 1, 31, 32, 33, 34]])
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all arrays starting with 1 you can use the following:

```
correct_data = all_data[all_data[:,:, 0] == 1]
```

It will reassign matching arrays to the desired variable.

Answer (score 0):

```py
correct_data = all_data[all_data[:, :, 0]==1]
```

The index here: `all_data[:, :, 0]==1` returns a boolean array where the 0th element in 3rd dimension is 1. Just use this to index the original array. You will get `array([[ 1, 31, 32, 33, 34]])` as the result.